# Как классифицировать "имеющим возникнуть"?

Tags: грамматика, историческая-грамматика

В Конституции СССР от 1924 года есть фраза:

> "... доступ в Союз открыт всем социалистическим   советским республикам, как существующим, так и **имеющим возникнуть** в будущем ...".

Что такое "имеющим возникнуть"? Это сокращение от словосочетания "имеющим *намерение* возникнуть" или это сложная причастная форма, состоящая из вспомогательного глагола "иметь" и смыслового глагола "возникать" (т.е. своего рода перфект будущего времени)?

P.S. Очень хотелось бы получить другие примеры этой конструкции из текстов.

Comment: Я имею предложить вам уйти на покой. Я имею сказать вам уйти на покой. Я имею быть с вами откровенным. https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CroCEpYCCpMCChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxJwChMKA2xleBIMCgrQuNC80LXRgtGMCgoKBGZvcm0SAgoAChMKBWdyYW1tEgoKCChwYXJ0Y3ApCgkKA3NlbRICCgAKFQoHc2VtLW1vZBIKCghzZW18c2VteAoJCgNzeW4SAgoACgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKABJxCgkKA2xleBICCgAKCgoEZm9ybRICCgAKEAoFZ3JhbW0SBwoFKGluZikKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoACgwKBGRpc3QiBAgBEAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQEwAQ==

Comment: И правда необычная для уха конструкция. Далеко не со всеми глаголами "иметь" может составлять СГС (составное глагольное сказуемое). Поэтому возникает какой-то диссонанс. Надо порыться на этот счет в энциклопедической грамматике

Comment: Это не должно быть сокращением (то есть у нас СГС, а не ПГС+дополнение+определение). Во-первых, потому, что неестественно что-то вставлять в приведенные мною выше примеры. Во-вторых, потому что "Этот случай имел быть в прошлом году" не может быть сокращением от "Этот случай имел место быть в прошлом году", так как "имеет место быть" общеизвестно-некорректное выражение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Примеры тут](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CroCEpYCCpMCChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxJwChMKA2xleBIMCgrQuNC80LXRgtGMCgoKBGZvcm0SAgoAChMKBWdyYW1tEgoKCChwYXJ0Y3ApCgkKA3NlbRICCgAKFQoHc2VtLW1vZBIKCghzZW18c2VteAoJCgNzeW4SAgoACgsKBWZsYWdzEgIKABJxCgkKA2xleBICCgAKCgoEZm9ybRICCgAKEAoFZ3JhbW0SBwoFKGluZikKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgkKA3N5bhICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoACgwKBGRpc3QiBAgBEAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQEwAQ==)

> 1. Н. В. Гоголь. Записки сумасшедшего (1835)
>    Но меня, однако же, чрезвычайно огорчало событие, **имеющее быть** завтра.
> 2. Борис Евсеев. Евстигней // «Октябрь», 2010
>    Выпала Евстигнеюшке редкая удача: сказать нечто об русских операх и вообще об **имеющей появиться** при конце века осьмнадцатого музыке.

Далее будем рассматривать связку **иметь + инфинитив** вместо **причастие+инфинитив**, так как это не меняет сути вопроса. Достаточно естественны выражения типа

```
Я имею предложить вам уйти на покой. 
Я имею сказать вам уйти на покой. 
Я имею быть с вами откровенным.
```

Очевидно, это не сокращения, так как ничего не вяжется в них вставлять.
Синтаксическая структура тут [следующая](http://philolog.pspu.ru/module/magazine/do/mpub_15_303)

> Инфинитив является дополнением, если спрягаемый глагол имеет
> полноценное лексическое значение, а действия глаголов относятся к
> разным лицам: Я прошу вас (о чем?) говорить по существу дела.

> Значительно реже встречаются случаи, когда инфинитив-дополнение
> обозначает действие того же субъекта: Вчера мы договорились (о чем?)
> поехать на дачу. За неделю он научился (чему?) кататься на коньках.
> Сестра быстро привыкла (к чему?) ухаживать за больной матерью.

То есть, тут нет никакого "вспомогательного" глагола, а есть полнозначный глагол **иметь**, у которого есть дополнение-инфинитив. Заметим также, что во многих случаях в подобные предложения можно впихнуть дополнение-прослойку, но это будут уже совсем другими предложениями:

```
За неделю он научился навыку кататься на коньках.
Сестра быстро привыкла к обязанности ухаживать за больной матерью.
Вчера мы договорились (???) поехать на дачу
```

С другой стороны не во все предложения по схеме иметь+инфинитив можно впихнуть существительное-прослойку:

```
 Этот случай имел быть/произойти в прошлом году
 Этот случай имел место быть в прошлом году //имел место быть - общепризнанная ошибка
```

Что тут действительно вызывает диссонанс, так это узкая лексическая сочетаемость иметь с другими глаголами.

```
Сестра привыкает делать... 
Сестра имеет делать ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы **на слух** перевела это так:

*"... доступ в Союз открыт всем социалистическим советским республикам, как существующим, так и **имеющим (возможность)** возникнуть в будущем ...".*